# How to capture from WDM Streaming audio sources (Realtek HD Audio)

Tags: windows, video-capture, directshow, audio-recording

I'm trying to use various audio sources in DirectShow and I have these capture devices in my system which I think are quite common (provided by chipset drivers):

Realtek HD Audio Line input
Realtek HD Audio Stereo input
Realtek HD Audio Mic input

They look like capture sources, expose analog input and 24-bit pcm output, and can connect the output to other filters (renderer etc).
But the return code from IMediaFilter::Run of the capture filter is ERROR_BAD_COMMAND which does not say much. I tried it in my program and also in GraphStudioNext which did not reveal any extra information.

Is it possible to use these for capture and how?

Update

For instance, I tried this graph with mic input (actually connected and working). In this setup, the graph does not start (ERROR_BAD_COMMAND) but with the other source, it would start.
This is the same device but different drivers. The one that works is from the category "Audio capture sources" the one that does not "WDM Streaming Capture Devices".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check the device with GraphStudioNext is to build a recording graph with the PCM audio input device itself, AVI Mux filter and File Writer filter connected as this (with default media types):

[image: enter image description here][1]

You hit Run and the recording graph produces non-empty file via Filter Writer in the location prompted during graph building.

--

So now I realized your question is a bit different. You see filters corresponding to your audio input device both under

- [Audio Capture Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/filter-categories) -- `CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory`
- WDM Streaming Capture Devices -- `AM_KSCATEGORY_CAPTURE`

And the question is that the first filter works and the other does not.

A similar filter from `AM_KSCATEGORY_CAPTURE` seems to be connecting into topology, but attempt to run triggers `ERROR_BAD_COMMAND`.

First of all, these are indeed different filters. Even though underlying hardware might be the same, the "frontend" filters are different. The wrapper that "works" is [Audio Capture Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/audio-capture-filter) backed by WDM device. In the other case it is Generic WDM Filter Proxy which behavior is, generally speaking, undefined. The filter is not documented and, I am guessing, it does not receive sufficient initialization or does not implement required behavior otherwise, so this proxy is not and is not supposed to be interchangeable with Audio Capture Filter proxy.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with graph picture and details. It seems the only conclusion I can make is something wrong with the driver.

Comment: Thanks for update. Despite this does not improve my understanding I accept that there is nothing I can do with it.